# Updated: How to checkmark select items from selection List by clicking Tableview cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview, segue

I am trying to retrieve selected item in tableView from `ViewController` which has a list from sqlite like checkmark selection. My `FirstViewController` have tableView and on clicking selective cell it opens `ViewController` to select items. 
Once selection has been made I have to reload `FirstViewController` tableview. Actually I am trying to do but not accurately doing. Anybody help me please to select item and set in tableview. I am confused and not able to do that passing selection via segue.
My github project link is below:

**My Project**: https://github.com/MasamMahmood/SqliteDataList/tree/master/SqliteDataList

Reference: https://blog.apoorvmote.com/how-to-pass-selection-via-segue/

Updated One FirstViewController:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewControlller, ListDelegate {

   var selectedIndex: Int?
   var selectedSection: Int?

   //Click event for navigation from FirstViewController to SecondViewController
   @IBAction func BackButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
       vc.delegate = self
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
   }

   func listFunc(listValue: String) {
       AppData?.sectionList?[selectedSection!].items?[selectedIndex!].textField = listValue
       tableView.reloadData()
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       //Add these two line in your code
       selectedIndex = indexPath.row
       selectedSection = indexPath.section
   } 
}
```

Updated SecondViewController:

```
protocol ListDelegate {
    func listFunc(listValue: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewControlller {
    var delegate: ListDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
        //print(currentCell.textLabel?.text as Any)
        currentCell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        delegate?.listFunc(listValue: currentCell.textLabel?.text ?? "")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a delegate to communicate back to the FirstViewController. You can do that like so...

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewControllerDidMakeSelection(at index: Int)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    weak var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.viewControllerDidMakeSelection(at: indexPath.row)
    }
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func viewControllerDidMakeSelection(at index: Int) {
        // This is where the magic happens
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, I have done that only getting small issue if you help me in that? My list is used in different tableview cell based on action type. But if I change the value at last it works fine but upper cell click it changed down cell row not the same index row/section. Can you help me in that? Actual click index row, section that value must be changed I am updating my question code.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear